# Ansible error message: 'ansible_user' is undefined

Tags: ansible

I get this error message when running a playbook locally and I cannot figure out why.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: /home/{{ new_user }}/.nvs: {{ ansible_user }}: 'ansible_user' is undefined

    The error appears to be in '/home/sturm/ansible-dotfiles/playbooks/prephome.yml': line 127, column 7, but may
    be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

    The offending line appears to be:


        - name: Clone the NVS repo
          ^ here
```

Here's the relevant part of the playbook:

```yaml
# playbooks/prephome.yml

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: true

  vars_files:
    - ../inventories/group_vars/all/vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Clone the NVS repo
      ansible.builtin.git:
        repo: https://github.com/jasongin/nvs
        dest: "{{ nvs_home }}"
        version: v1.6.0
```

And the relevant portion of the variables file:

```yaml
# inventories/group_vars/all/vars.yml

new_user: "{{ ansible_user }}"
nvs_home: "/home/{{ new_user }}/.nvs"
```

I thought `ansible_user` was a built-in variable that always had a value. How can it possibly be 'undefined?'

I've seen other issues talk about how they cannot use `ansible_user` if their task has `become_user` in it, but this task clearly does not. So what else could be the problem?

**EDIT:** I guess I should also note that, when running the playbook, I use the command:

```sh
ansible-playbook -K -i "localhost," -c local ./playbooks/prephome.yml
```

**EDIT 2:** It might help to see [repository](https://github.com/SturmB/ansible-dotfiles) from which this problem stems.

Comment: its not reproducible at my env.

Comment: Worked fine for me, too.  But why do you have the `vars_files` bit?  If the file is in the inventory, it will be picked up.

Comment: @Jack IIRC, the playbook didn't pick up the `vars.yml` file despite being in the correct folder for automatic pick-up. So I had to explicitly call it. Perhaps both problems can be traced back to the same cause? I went ahead and added a link to the repo in case the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Possibly.  `-i "localhost"` looks fishy to me.  The `-i` option points to your inventory file.  Shouldn't that be `-i ../inventories`?

Comment: @Jack No, according to [their docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-playbook.html#cmdoption-ansible-playbook-i), it does not point to an inventory file; it allows you to specify a host path or a list of hosts. I'm using it to call out the 'localhost' host in the inventory file. (Which, incidentally, is the only host in the inventory right now. And it even specifies `ansible_user` for that host!)

Comment: @Sturm Never seen it used that way.  I use the path to the inventory directory, then `--limit`.  But it does explain why `group_vars/all` is not getting read automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: I changed the playbook command to:

```sh
ansible-playbook -K ./playbooks/prephome.yml
```

---

Having a discussion with Jack made me realize that the `-i "localhost," -c local` portion of the command was not only unnecessary—because I only have a 'localhost' in the inventory—but it was somehow causing the playbook to not see the `group_vars` files and not set the `ansible_user` var.

I still don't know the exact reason for it—my money is on the `-c local` argument. I would certainly be interested as to why removing those arguments from the playbook command suddenly makes the playbook run flawlessly.